# Is it possible to use Allatori on Kotlin source code?

Tags: java, kotlin, obfuscation, allatori

I've tried to use Allatori in the past and regardless of disabling a lot of options, I couldn't get it to apply to actual Kotlin bytecode - I had to exclude the Kotlin files in order for the obfuscation to work.

Is it possible to use Allatori obfuscation on Kotlin bytecode? If so, which options need to be disabled?

Comment: Did you manage to use Allatori with Kotlin?